# ¿Cómo hacer un text delay en Python dentro de un panel en Rich?

Tags: python

En Stack busqué cómo hacer un delay, y me apareció un código que terminé "adaptando" a la librería de Rich. Al menos después de 1 hora de intentos, ya no dice error. Pero ahora por cada caracter del texto crea un panel distinto... ¿Cómo arreglo eso?

```
# Retrasar texto
def delay(text, delay):
    for i in text:
        time.sleep(delay)
        console.print(Panel(f"[bright_white]{i}"), style="rosy_brown", height=y, justify="center", end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    console.print()
```

Comment: Eso ocurre por que recorres el texto. Simplemente no lo recorras.

Comment: @Christian ¿A qué te refieres con recorrer el texto? Y, ¡gracias por ayudar! :)

Comment: `for i in text:` estas recorriendo cada caracter del texto. O acaso `text` es una lista?

Comment: Claro, lo estoy recorriendo para que haga ese efecto de 'delay', como si se estuviera escribiendo poco a poco. Logré hacer ese efecto sin nada de Rich, luego intenté adaptarlo y salió un poco mal. Las líneas 5 y 7 eran `print(i, end='')`, `print()`.